# User asking separate questions to essentially have SO users create their whole application

Tags: discussion, questions

Earlier i answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424163/bootstrap-button-dropdown-with-custom-content) about a button drop down containing a form rather than a list of buttons. There was no feedback for my answer, which did not matter to me until I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433249/keep-bootstrap-button-dropdown-open-on-click) to see the same user, using the answer I provided and asking for help on the next step of his problem.

Normally if a user does not attempt to answer something - they get pretty negative feedback from the community. But in this user's case, he is making it seem like he is attempting the problem when he is actually just using previous answers to ask more questions.

Do we do anything about this case?

1. Comment and tell them they need to attempt solutions and not copy and paste another partially complete solution from someone else as their 'attempt'
2. Flag the post for a mod and explain the low quality of the question
3. Ignore it?

Comment: It is interesting that the user has asked hundreds of questions, still most of them are well received. I don't see any problem if they asked a couple of questions in the same day. I don't think that this is a vampire problem.

Comment: @user000001 I noticed the same thing. And most other questions the user posted are very well written. Something concerns me about this case.

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Should SO get the proceeds from iPhone apps coded by answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94675)

Comment: **Please don't go mob-downvoting these questions!**

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat , i do not agree with 'mob-downvoting' but low quality and off topic questions are usually downvoted.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't telling that to you; my comment was to everybody who sees this.

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat - too late. That's like asking gravity not to pull...

Comment: Where's my flaming torch and pitchfork? I know they're around here somewhere...

Answer (score 3):

To answer this problem in general, not this specific case: I see nothing wrong with this behavior. As long as the questions are clear, not too broad, and he doesn't say he wrote the code himself, he isn't breaking any rules. The only real reason he can't say "plz write teh ntier codez 4 me" is because then a *single* person would have to completely answer the question. If he asks about how to do a smallish thing, or he asks about a specific problem with code, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Fair enough(although i disagree), but include how you feel about this case because I am curious.

Comment: @JordanD in this specific case, my answer applies. The only difference is that Idsa's questions aren't great quality, and should be closed. The fact that all the questions are related in the way they are should not affect anything.

Comment: But these questions are very low quality - and the user has made no attempts to solve the problem. It is on par with the 'do my homework' questions.

Comment: @JordanD Yes, they are bad, and should be closed. In my answer, I was addressing the question of what to do about users who basically build an entire program by asking a lot of small questions.

Comment: If the code is a direct copy of the other answer, it should be credited to the person who answered (because of the cc by-sa 3.0 license).  If it is a sufficiently modified version of the previous answer (for some ill-defined definition of 'sufficiently'), then maybe the credit isn't necessary, though it would still be sensible/courteous to say something along the lines of "Building on the answer [...url to answer...], I've done ... and now my problem is ...".  But that requires a certain amount of maturity, perhaps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , so since he used the exact bootply i gave him?...

Comment: You could either add credit to the answer or as a comment. I would probably add it to the answer and only as a comment if the edit was rolled back or otherwise deleted.