# What should we do when a user does not learn from previous answers and keeps on asking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, help-vampire

In the past nine hours I noticed a series of similar questions from the same user, regarding the same topic, but in incremental steps.

Here is the first question: *[Error in Code with Quadratic Formula Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347991/error-in-code-with-quadratic-formula-program)*. The user claims to be new to the Python programming language, so I suppose it is quite frequent to encounter some issues, errors, etc.

After a few hours the user asks about again basic Python variable passing/returning:  *[Using a Function inside a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350543/using-a-function-inside-a-function)*

Here at the end of the answer the answerer has clearly stated to:

> Of course, you're going to want to ensure your values are converted to integers to perform math...

Here is the third question: *[Quadratic equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351884/quadratic-equations)*. The user asks about the same program to evaluate those and someone answers the question by saying you need to cast it. But the user does not seem to learn from the answers on his question and keeps on asking the same type of question again.

Here is the fourth question: *[Arithmetic with Functions in Python for a Novice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352534/arithmetic-with-functions-in-python-for-a-novice)*. In this question the user basically asks the third question, and someone answers it stating the same result, which is to cast it.

I don't have an issue with answering such questions, although they can be solved pretty easily, but the problem is here that the user does not seem to learn from the answers and does not accept any answers and seems to just throw up his hands at the slightest of errors. It would be much better to redirect the user to a beginners tutorial on Python IMHO.

The similar questions I've found on the site do not answer my question.

Comment: Such questions shouldn't be answered actually. Finding the proper duplicate and moving to dupe-closing is likely better. You say you are ok answering these questions but then ask how to stop answering them.... Simple: don't answer them. Don't train the user in getting his answer when he's asking a poorly researched question about a concept he doesn't understand fully

Comment: @Patrice I haven't answered any of the users questions, that was my first thought and I stuck with it. But this series of questions from the users made me think about posting this to meta. I do get that the user is a beginner and they must be redirected so some source, but SO should not be the one.

Comment: oh I know, I didn't say you answered them. I'm just saying that's the best way (and also explaining why 'I don't have an issue answering such questions' isn't necessarily the proper stance on the first place). Then, using our curation tools (downvoting If the questions are poor/poorly researched, and closing/flagging for duplication when appropriate). As for pointing the user somewhere,that is definitely an option. doesn't mean it'll be well received or that it's even necessary, but it's something that can be done through comments with the user

Comment: Incompetent deadbeat continually posts 'Computers 101' question, SO rep---hunters provide answers.  It's a law of the universe, one of the postulates of special relativity and written in the Qur'an, Bible, Torah etc.  Stopping homework vamps will get you a Nobel and   Sainthood.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [User asking separate questions to essentially have SO users create their whole application](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269460). The general recommendation is to handle each question in isolation. If it doesn't meet our standards, vote to close it. If it doesn't meet your standards, downvote it. You shouldn't be moderating users; you should moderate questions. If you really think a user is a continual source of low-quality questions, you can raise a custom mod flag on one of the questions and ask us to reach out to them.

Comment: IMO all of these questions should be closed as they do not include a clear problem statement. I can't even figure out what exactly the OP is struggling with in the first three questions - there's basically just a problem statement and a few lines of code fetching the coefficients and printing the result. E.g. in the first question, OP says "I am getting errors with it" and "the one on top doesn't work because it has a space" (wat?) but the code looks fine (it's not doing much but shouldn't throw errors). Too bad that closing crap questions isn't as important as being _welcoming_ nowadays...

Comment: And before anybody says "it was always this way", no, these kinds of "coding by iterative StackOverflow query" questions were indeed closed in the past. I still want my "lacks minimal understanding" close reason back...

Comment: @l4mpi Closing crap questions has nothing whatsoever to do with being welcoming. Calling questions “crap” is...somewhat unwelcoming, so you should neatly sidestep that problem by not calling the question *anything* and simply voting to close. “Lacks minimal understanding” was removed because it was misused. We don’t really care what understanding the asker has; answers are for more than just them. What is important is that the question is clear, reasonably scoped, and on-topic. We have close reasons to capture all of those problems.

Comment: Related: *[Help Vampires: A Spotter's Guide](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)* - "As soon as an open source project, language, or what-have-you achieves a certain notoriety—its half-life, if you will— *they* swarm in, seemingly draining the very life out of the community itself. *They* are the Help Vampires."

Comment: You up vote them and keep answering their endless questions, with well written **detailed** answers. That is the charter of the site now. ***With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.*** [Every question is sacred!](https://youtu.be/bzVHjg3AqIQ?t=103) Anything else is *unwelcoming*. Do you see any mention of *quality* in the charter anymore? Search the *[Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)* page for the word quality yourself if you do not believe me. More questions means more answers and more answers is what it about!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal appropriately with answers posted for obvious help vampire questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286230/how-to-deal-appropriately-with-answers-posted-for-obvious-help-vampire-questions)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for repeating the usual arguments, but that doesn't change facts. Fact is, a few years ago these questions would have been hammered with the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason. Nowadays, this crap gets answered instead. Also, the four linked questions are so localized that I doubt they're ever going to help anybody else than the OP. And I couldn't care less about being unwelcoming towards people who clearly demostrate they are not a "professional or enthusiast" programmer, as I don't believe we should welcome these people here until they've at least learned the basics.

Comment: @l4mpi thanks for repeating what the community standards were 4 years ago, they are not that now. They are pretty much the opposite. You are not even beating a dead horse. You are beating one that was purposefully killed. See my previous comment for my opinion on what they are now.

Comment: the account has now been deleted. I don't have the details about that deletion BTW

Comment: Aaand the trash is cleaned up, thanks to the Meta Effect.

Comment: Maybe related:  [are-we-fine-with-iteratively-asking-questions-to-get-to-a-coded-solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380545/are-we-fine-with-iteratively-asking-questions-to-get-to-a-coded-solution)

Comment: And I though this question had to do with [Remove match word from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56393207/608639), [Print text after last slash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56394666/608639), [How to extract Text from large text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56395686/608639), and several others. They are incremental, no effort, give me the code questions. Plenty of dups but we could not close them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's what you should do with questions like these:

- Downvote questions that do not demonstrate any research done by OP. You should liberally downvote any question where the OP clearly doesn't understand basic programming principles - askers should learn the basics of the language they are tring to program in before asking a question. This applies to all four linked questions.
- Vote to close (or flag, in your case) any questions that do not clearly describe a problem. If the OP fails to ask a question, or you have to guess what the specific issue is, that means you should vote to close. If OP just says "this code throws an error" without providing a stacktrace and/or specific error message, this should be closed as well in most cases. This applies to the first three of the four linked questions. The fourth is not good but could be considered close enough - OP included the error message but failed to mention where the error is thrown, but we can get that info from the code without much effort.

Furthermore, you say that

> It would be much better to redirect the user to a beginners tutorial on Python IMHO.

and I entirely agree on that. Sadly I don't think StackExchange the company would agree with us... not sure if it's because they honestly believe it would be better for the user to be spoon-fed by other SO users or because they get less ad revenue if users are directed to off-site resources. Anyways, there is not yet a rule against telling people exactly that, as long as you do it in a *welcoming* way. So you are free to write a comment such as this:

> Hello $USER, thank you for your question. It seems like you've started programming in $LANGUAGE very recently and might not have a clear understanding of the [syntax|concepts|tools|...]. In that case, I would recommend you read the following tutorial about the subject, which should enable you to solve your problem by yourself: $LINK"

Remember that writing such a comment does not mean you should not downvote and vote/flag to close whereever applicable. Also, from personal experience I can tell you that many users will not appreciate such a comment, no matter how polite you word it - they expect to be spoon fed and might even react with hostility to anything that implies they should personally invest some effort. Thus I would recommend downvoting, closevoting and moving on with your life.

Comment: *"You should liberally downvote any question where the OP clearly doesn't understand basic programming principles"* pretty sure that violates the *vote on the content not the user*?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: in order for someone to demonstrate that they "clearly don't understand basic programming principles" they obviously have to express it through their content.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson not sure why you think so. You make determination of what OP did by content.

Comment: +1 and last paragraph is useful advice to keep in mind

Comment: @JarrodRoberson the question downvote arrow tooltip reads "This question does not show any research effort; [...]". I would expect learning the basics of the programming language under question to be required research. The "vote on the content, not on the user" guideline IMO just means you should evaluate the post on its own, without letting OPs other posts or metadata (race, gender, etc - and even if they are new to SO and/or programming) influence your decision.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the guidelines given by SE are not absolute law. If the community decides to ignore a guideline, it's worthless. And just because SE decided that specific things should be handled in specific ways doesn't mean anybody has to agree with them on that. As long as you're not actively breaking site rules, you're free to do what you want. E.g. just because SE decided we should pamper new users doesn't mean I have to change my voting habits if I encounter a new user; if I see a question that I personally think is bad I'm free to downvote it.

Answer (score 9):

*"I don't have an issue with answering such questions,..."* you should, because by answering them it just gives positive reinforcement to the OP behavior of spamming the site every few mins with the next thing they need to figure out with as little effort as possible. Ideally there should be enough people voting to close them quickly enough that they never stay open long enough to get answered. That has never happened and never will. With the "Every question is scared!" culture 
now making very loud and repetitive arguments that closing and down voting should not even exist, it is even more of a waste of time and less and less people are actively moderating.

But all that said, it is very explicit that there it is not allowed to even consider any **person** skill level when voting on anything. Only the content. Voting because of the person is not allowed for any reason ever.

There is no facilities for the community moderating people directly or their behavior on SO and it has been made really clear there never will be.

Comment: moderators have a "question repetition" and "consistently low quality questions over time" contact reasons. It's true that users should not focus on persons, but moderators do that.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you at all but sadly this answer is not constructive.  (I.e.,: doesn't propose useful action.)  But that's ok as @l4mpi covered that.